# Extracting the first frame from a video in m2t format using Delphi

Tags: delphi, video, thumbnails

We have a bunch of video files in **m2t** format.
How can we generate thumbnails (by extracting the first frame) from these files using Delphi?

Comment: This has little to do with Delphi. You need either a format specification for M2T, which tells you how you can get that data or search for components that can load M2T files.

Comment: @Smasher: Yes and no. Of course, I think that it can be solved using a general solution but a Delphi library/API calls/code which can read the M2T is the preffered solution. Yep, I googled (using several keywords) for this but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [IExtractImage interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761848%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to request this image from Windows. Windows in turn grabs it from some driver, which you must enable by adding the following registry entries:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mts\ShellEx\{BB2E617C-0920-11D1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}]
@="{c5a40261-cd64-4ccf-84cb-c394da41d590}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.m2t\ShellEx\{BB2E617C-0920-11D1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}]
@="{c5a40261-cd64-4ccf-84cb-c394da41d590}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.m2ts\ShellEx\{BB2E617C-0920-11D1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}]
@="{c5a40261-cd64-4ccf-84cb-c394da41d590}"
```

You can verify that it worked if you see thumbnails in the Explorer for your files. It's those thumbnails your app retrieves.

This saves you from the trouble of having to do some extremely complex file decoding and/or interfacing with some lib for which you must first convert the headers yourself.